# How can a diffable collection view display the same item in multiple sections?

Tags: ios, swift, diffabledatasource

My app presents an emoji keyboard like Apple's where the emoji are displayed by-category. I render this using a collection view where the categories are sections. If an emoji has been inserted recently, it should appear in the "Frequently Used" category as well as whatever category it's normally in.

This is a problem for me trying to convert my collection view to use a `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, because `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` requires that items are unique. If I do something like

```swift
let snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Emoji>()
snapshot.appendItems([thumbsUpEmoji], toSection: .frequents)
snapshot.appendItems([thumbsUpEmoji], toSection: .smileys)
dataSource.apply(snapshot)
```

I get warnings like

> inserted identifier(s) already present; existing items will be moved into place for this current insertion. Please note this will impact performance if items are not unique when inserted.

And the emoji only shows up in one section, not both. How can I insert the item into multiple sections?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found that I was able to do this by wrapping the emoji in structs that associated the emoji to their sections:

```swift
struct CategorizedEmoji: Hashable {
    let emoji: Emoji
    let category: Section
}
```

My datasource is then of type `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CategorizedEmoji>` and the snapshots of type `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CategorizedEmoji>`. When constructing the snapshot I do

```swift
let snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CategorizedEmoji>()
snapshot.appendItems([CategorizedEmoji(emoji: thumbsUpEmoji, category: .frequents)], toSection: .frequents)
snapshot.appendItems([CategorizedEmoji(emoji: thumbsUpEmoji, category: .smileys)], toSection: .smileys)
dataSource.apply(snapshot)
```

A little verbose but really not too bad.

*Caveat*: I would guess that this solution would prevent the emoji from moving between sections (since an emoji in a different section would be represented by a completely different item). I personally don't need to handle that but I'd welcome seeing an answer that did figure that out.

Comment: I've just come across the same problem and solved it like this. My mental model is: The CategorizedEmoji is a unique representation of the data for the view, or a viewModel, not a direct 1-1 with my underlying data models. If your emoji update, you could still find all the CategorizedEmoji structs and update them.

Comment: @Morgz I like that mental model. Re: updating the emoji, yeah I could find all the CategorizedEmoji structs and update them. What I mean though is that I think the collection view would treat that update as a removal from one section and an insertion in another section rather than a move between sections, given that the struct in the new section would not hash to the same value as the struct in the old section. I haven't tested that though.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great! Took some rework but it's a perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic implementation so you can use this for all your sectioned lists:

```
/// The following allows items to be used across different shard key-spaces, by combining a shard's hash values with the item's hash.
///
/// EXAMPLE: For sectioned UICollectionViews, simply use a section identifier as the sharding key to allow items to show up in multiple sections-
struct ShardedItem<TShardingKey, TItem> : Hashable
    where TShardingKey:Hashable, TItem:Hashable
{
    let shard:TShardingKey
    let item:TItem
}
```

Then simply use it like so:

*NOTE: Uses iOS 14 [sectioned snapshots](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-an-expandable-list-using-uicollectionview-part-1-703312c2d773)*

```
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, ShardedItem<Section, Thing>>()
snapshot.appendSections( [.topThings, .allThings] )
self.dataSource.apply( snapshot, animatingDifferences: false )

let allThings:[Thing] = ...
let topThings:[Thing] = allThings.filter{ $0.isFeatured }
var topThingsSectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ShardedItem<Section, Thing>>()
topThingsSectionSnapshot.append( topThings.map { ShardedItem( shard: .topThings, item: $0 )})
self.dataSource.apply( topThingsSectionSnapshot, to: .topThings )

var allThingsSectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ShardedItem<MinorRegionsSection, MinorRegionListItem>>()
allThingsSectionSnapshot.append( allThings.map { ShardedItem( shard: .allThings, item: $0 )})
self.dataSource.apply( allThingsSectionSnapshot, to: .allThings )
```

Comment: Great solution - the composite object way of doing it is a bit of a pain